# How to make WPF DataGrid VerticalScrollBar Always Visible?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

Do you knows how to make the WPF `DataGrid` `VerticalScrollBar` always visible, even if there is no data to display without putting `DataGrid` object instid a `ScrollViewer`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to set the [ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx) attached property like so:

```
<DataGrid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ...
```

Comment: I tried this before,  but it doesn't work with me, did you tried it?

Comment: @Mohammed - I just did a quick test and it worked fine. Can you post your code in your question?

Comment: I tried your solution on a new project and it worked just fine!, it seems that I have something in my DataGrid style that prevents the scroll viewer from always being visible. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @MohammedA.Fadil, have you found any problems preventing the scrollbar always visible? Same error occured to me, if you have fix this problem, please tell me how to make it,thanks!